# document.ready inside html angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am adding my template on angular I already have all imported script and css but to initialize the scripts the plantilla asks to initialize the global variable that is App.init within document ready on the main index, that would be in the main index of Angular if work with ts

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //initialize the javascript
   App.init();
});
```

that initializes my template scripts to work properly , how that line would be implemented in the main angular index

Comment: can you please provide code which you have tried ?

Comment: What's "plantilla"? Why are you mixing jQuery with Angular?

Comment: It is not that I am mixing it, but I already had a template and I wanted to use it is a new project that will be angular, although I found a request to execute the init was not working and I changed it, this is due to how to mention in Your comment seems that the template is worked with jquery and therefore it gave me trouble @Edric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with next:

```
window.onload = function() {
  App.init();
};
```

Comment: your code if you replace the document ready however the template gave problems apparently this one with jquery